# I created database and named it table1 , My sql code is given how to fix this error?

Tags: mysql, wampserver

```
mysql> use table1;
Database changed
mysql> create table customer(cust_no varchar(5),cust_name varchar(15),age number,phone number(15));
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'number,phone number(15))' at line 1
mysql>
```

Comment: The link is unreadable, please include your code , table definitions sample data desired outcome and any error messages as text in the question

Comment: *MySQL supports all standard SQL numeric data types which include INTEGER, SMALLINT, DECIMAL, and NUMERIC*, so **number** is not  a valid MySQL datatype. I'm voting to close this question as typo

Comment: Suggestion, don't store age but store birthdate and you can calculate the age. it is better to store phone as string not numeric ...https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e59fc5b21e65be12154946b14cb24df4

Answer (score 0):

MySQL dones't have a `number` datatype. It is called `numeric`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead, simply changing to accepted datatypes:

```
create table customer(cust_no varchar(5), cust_name varchar(15), age 
tinyint, phone varchar(15));
```